# SSL connection failing for Java 7

Tags: java, ssl

I am attempting to create an SSL connection to a remote server using Java 7 and I'm receiving the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at ssl7.Client.main(Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
```

When I rerun the code using Java 6, there is no exception.  I have found references to this problem elsewhere on StackOverflow but my situation comes with a twist.  The client code, which fails with Java 7 is

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("login.solon.com", 443);    
            OutputStream outputstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
            BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);
                bufferedwriter.write("hello\n");
                bufferedwriter.flush();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I add the line

```
sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5"});
```

after creating the socket, it works.

now, `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` exists in the original set of cipher suites so all I've done is add restrictions.  Restricting the cipher suites is not a viable solution in the long run.  Can anyone explain what is going on here?

The full debug log is:

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Temp\keystore\clientkeystore
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=W, OU=D, O=S, L=H, ST=I, C=IL
  Issuer:  CN=W, OU=D, O=S, L=H, ST=I, C=IL
  Algorithm: DSA; Serial number: 0x4a6e05b7
  Valid from Mon Oct 07 10:22:54 EEST 2013 until Sun Jan 05 09:22:54 EET 2014

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=login.solon.com, OU=Domain Validated, OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate, OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html
  Issuer:  CN=Thawte DV SSL CA, OU=Domain Validated SSL, O="Thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3012ec22473f20aa2cdc4bf7fe2d22f4
  Valid from Wed Feb 13 02:00:00 EET 2013 until Thu Apr 14 02:59:59 EEST 2016

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=W, OU=D, O=S, L=H, ST=I, C=IL
  Issuer:  CN=W, OU=D, O=S, L=H, ST=I, C=IL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x5864235a
  Valid from Mon Oct 07 10:28:06 EEST 2013 until Sun Jan 05 09:28:06 EET 2014

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1381093608 bytes = { 221, 239, 107, 239, 150, 213, 224, 210, 101, 229, 42, 58, 92, 9, 151, 0, 128, 105, 0, 55, 53, 224, 90, 111, 130, 175, 61, 121 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 149
0000: 01 00 00 91 03 01 52 52   D1 E8 DD EF 6B EF 96 D5  ......RR....k...
0010: E0 D2 65 E5 2A 3A 5C 09   97 00 80 69 00 37 35 E0  ..e.*:\....i.75.
0020: 5A 6F 82 AF 3D 79 00 00   2A C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  Zo..=y..*...../.
0030: 04 C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0   07 C0 11 00 05 C0 02 C0  ....3.2.........
0040: 0C C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0   03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00  ................
0050: 04 00 FF 01 00 00 3E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......>...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00                                     .....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
[Raw write]: length = 154
0000: 16 03 01 00 95 01 00 00   91 03 01 52 52 D1 E8 DD  ...........RR...
0010: EF 6B EF 96 D5 E0 D2 65   E5 2A 3A 5C 09 97 00 80  .k.....e.*:\....
0020: 69 00 37 35 E0 5A 6F 82   AF 3D 79 00 00 2A C0 09  i.75.Zo..=y..*..
0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0 11  .../.....3.2....
0040: 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0 08   C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D  ................
0050: 00 16 00 13 00 04 00 FF   01 00 00 3E 00 0A 00 34  ...........>...4
0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00                    ..........
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 28                               ......(
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at ssl7.Client.main(Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    ... 10 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Particularly nicely formatted question! Keep it up!

Comment: Perhaps your code needs a firmer handshake. I know I refuse all connections with a weak handshake.

Comment: Which specific java versions are you using?  Both on the client and server.

Comment: I ran the code on Java 1.7.0_21 vs 1.6.0_25

Comment: The server is running 1.7.0_21

Comment: On which platform is the server running?

Answer (score 8):

I have seen this sort of problem before when using an Ubuntu 12.04 server running a Java-based server using its OpenJDK package. (This may have been patched since, as I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the latest updates, but my configuration might be slightly different, I can't remember.)

This was essentially the problem described in [this Ubuntu issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1006776).

There was essentially an issue with the EC calculation on the server side, which prevented the connection to be established correctly.

There is a difference in the preference order for the cipher suites between [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) and [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) (see both tables).

Because `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` is higher than any EC cipher suite in the preference order in Java 6 (and supported by both client and server), it will be chosen when you connect with a Java 6 client.

When you connect with a Java 7 client, some EC cipher suites (e.g. `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` or `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`) will be chosen and the server will start to proceed with this (you'd need to see the handshake debug log on the server side to confirm this). The server would then be done with the cipher suite selection process, but fail to go any further because of a subsequent bug when trying to use this cipher suite.

If you have some control over the server (and if it's indeed running a Java-based server), try to upgrade to the latest JRE packages. You can also try the fixes suggested in the Ubuntu issue (especially if it's not using PKCS#11) or to disable the ECDHE cipher suites in the server configuration.

Answer (score 4):

From a glance at your server configuration (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=login.solon.com) compared to your list of available cipher suites in Java7, it appears you have only two accepted options for your cipher suite:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Now, `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` is considered weak, but since your server declares no preference for order, it may be picking this and then failing the handshake. For Java6, it's entirely possible it just happens to be picking a stronger suite. The more options you give it, the more chances you have of giving it a chance to pick a weak cipher, so when you specify a single suite to use, it succeeds. (Although in looking at your server configuration, I'm not sure how you were getting `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` to succeed as it is apparently not supported.) On that train of thought, perhaps you should try limiting your cipher suites to only:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Or more specifically:

```
sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"});
```

Comment: Why is the DHE_RSA cipher weak? TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA has perfect forward secrecy, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA does not, and they are otherwise the same.

Comment: To answer my own comment, for whatever reason the `SunJSSE` crypto provider in Java 6 and Java 7 uses 768-bit DH keys, and there doesn't seem to be a way to change it, which is a shame because the only work around is to disable DHE suites.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to answer your own comment because I was not aware of that. =)

Answer (score 0):

It's Java 7's compatibility issue with keystores. Convert your keystore file into .p12 . It should work using that.

Comment: Where did you get that idea? There's no keystore on the client side here.

Answer (score -4):

did you include the truststore when you execute the client?

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${resources}/localhost.truststore \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD -jar client.jar com.acme.RunClient
```

Comment: Read the question. It is obvious from the trace that he has a truststore. In any case a question is. It an answer.