# Java 8 javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated, but not Java 7

Tags: java, ssl, java-8

I have an issue when switching my application from Java 7 to Java 8.  After changing the JDK I start getting this SSLPeerUnverified Exception.  Changing back to Java7, there is no exception.

I found this question: [SSL connection failing for Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228862/ssl-connection-failing-for-java-7) which implies that this may be related to a server side issue. Our server is indeed running on an Ubuntu machine, but it is running Java8 as well (sun Java8)

Not sure what else would be helpful to post. I can provide code samples if needed/useful.  I didn't incude them now because it appears as though the code is not the issue.

Edit - link to my extension of SSLSocketFactory: http://pastebin.com/2j6HDHE7

Edit2 - Http client code:

```
    private HttpClient getHttpClient() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        trustStore.load(CommandChannel.class.getResourceAsStream("myKeystore"), "myPassword".toCharArray());

        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new TrustingSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);

        final SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, sslSocketFactory));

        final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParamBean paramsBean = new HttpProtocolParamBean(params);
        paramsBean.setVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        paramsBean.setContentCharset("UTF_8");

        final ClientConnectionManager ccm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(registry);
        final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

        return httpClient;
    }
```

Including the SSL-debug information from java8 & java7 below.

Java 8 SSL debug trace:

```
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1389745002 bytes = { 220, 201, 110, 4, 38, 166, 25, 166, 235, 253, 71, 242, 226, 124, 22, 149, 28, 207, 242, 25, 201, 123, 218, 56, 207, 67, 195, 17 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
JavaFX Application Thread, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
JavaFX Application Thread, received EOFException: error
JavaFX Application Thread, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
JavaFX Application Thread, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
JavaFX Application Thread, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
JavaFX Application Thread, called closeSocket()
JavaFX Application Thread, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
JavaFX Application Thread, called close()
JavaFX Application Thread, called closeInternal(true)
JavaFX Application Thread, called close()
JavaFX Application Thread, called closeInternal(true)
18:49:14,951 ERROR [logger] [LoginController] Error logging in due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
com.limebrokerage.portal.communication.command.CommandChannelException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

Java 7 SSL debug trace of the same bit of code:

```
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1389746267 bytes = { 91, 88, 192, 29, 58, 48, 211, 105, 40, 40, 138, 204, 154, 113, 233, 213, 120, 99, 3, 223, 26, 233, 123, 150, 251, 245, 186, 246 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
JavaFX Application Thread, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
JavaFX Application Thread, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1389746267 bytes = { 179, 44, 184, 192, 189, 56, 33, 48, 248, 204, 248, 129, 1, 214, 77, 185, 206, 200, 3, 148, 58, 49, 98, 42, 213, 229, 106, 218 }
Session ID:  {83, 214, 216, 91, 179, 44, 184, 192, 189, 56, 33, 48, 248, 204, 248, 129, 1, 214, 77, 185, 206, 200, 3, 148, 58, 49, 98, 42, 213, 229, 106, 218}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
JavaFX Application Thread, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1522
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
```

Comment: What is the URL for the server?

Comment: Do you use any self-signed certificates on the server? If yes, those need to be manually added to JDK's the keychain

Comment: @dimoniy - No self signed certs on the server.  Server has a cert signed by verisign (expires in 2017)

Comment: It could be useful to see a fragment of code: `SSLSocket`, `SSLEngine`, `HttpsURLConnection`? Do you start the handshake explicitly? Does it happen with Java 8 on the client and Java 7 on the server?

Comment: @Bruno - Added sample code - I can provide more but these seem like the most relevant portions.

Comment: It looks like Apache HTTP Client, which exact version is it?

Comment: Note that the TMF you're using is vulnerable to MITM attacks. It seems pointless to bypass certificate verification (which is what it does) when you actually go to the trouble of making it load a truststore (which is what you should generally do... but you should also use that truststore of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not for sure an answer, but too long for a comment.

Your real problem is the server disconnect on hello and resulting `SSLHandshakeException`; `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` is collateral damage because the handshake didn't reach the authentication stage. The obvious difference is that Java 8 is sending TLSv1.2 ClientHello where Java 7 sent TLSv1.

Java 7 implemented 1.1 and 1.2, but didn't *enable* them on client by default; 8 does, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7093640 . A correctly written server stack that doesn't support 1.2 *should* negotiate down to 1.1 or 1(.0), but your unidentified server apparently doesn't, or possibly something in-between like a firewall is messing up your connection. If you have or get OpenSSL, commandline `openssl s_client` will let you easily try different versions (and ciphers and some options) to see what does and does not work. Or you could have https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ do their canned but fairly thorough tests.

The bug entry says you can set sysprop `jdk.tls.client.protocols` and that works for me in a minimal SSLSocket (not HTTP) app on 8u05. Or since you're already doing a modified `SSLSocketFactory`, I expect you could do `setEnabledProtocols` on the sockets you create.

FWIW, when OpenSSL release 1.0.1 in March 2012 "silently" turned on protocols 1.1 and 1.2 (it was prominent in the release notes, but approximately nobody reads release notes), the support list got lots of complaints, I'd guess over a hundred total, of servers that suddenly started failing, crashing, or hanging until clients reverted to 1.0. OpenSSL ended up implementing a workaround that can artificially decrease or increase some data in the ClientHello to avoid the most "provocative" sizes; I don't know if JSSE does or can do something similar.

Comment: This, this was it! I can't believe I didn't notice the version difference in my own ssl debug trace output! We were able to get things working following your advice and doing: "setEnabledProtocols(“TLSv1”);" For the moment we'll work with that.  Thanks!